# Reference counting in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, reference-counting

I assume according to "Cocoa design patterns" book i'm reading that the retain function is implemented using something like this :

```
   - (int)retainCount
// Returns the receiver's current reference count
{
int result = 1; // receiver not in table, its count is 1
void *tableValue = NSMapGet(
[[self class] _myRefCountMapTable], self);
if(NULL != tableValue )
{ // if receiver is in table, its count is the value stored
result = (int)tableValue;
}
return result;
}

- (id)retain
// Increases the receiver's reference count
{
// store the increased value in the table
NSMapInsert([[self class] _myRefCountMapTable], self,
(void *)([self retainCount] + 1));
return self;
}
```

As the example imply every reference object has the same self member.
How does that happen ? maybe I don't understand the meaning of self - I though it's like "this" in C++.

If I just use assignment operator (A=B) Does it copy the pointer(self) and that's it ?
I though it would use "copywithzone" and it's relatives and the "self" members won't be equal. 
Moreover, I though copywithzone is like copy constructor in c++.

I guess i'm confusing between the 2 worlds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the example imply every reference object …

There is no such thing as a “reference object”. I suspect that's not what you meant, so please clarify.

> has the same self member.

Objects do not have members (instances have instance variables, which are similar in concept but not the same in implementation).

`self` is not a “member”, nor is it an instance variable. Note that classes have `self` as well. `self` is a special hidden argument to the message, containing the object that is the receiver of the message.

And no, `self` does not refer to every object at once. If you send the same message to two different objects, even of the same class, the `self` argument will contain a different pointer in each message.

> maybe I don't understand the meaning of self - I though it's like "this" in C++.

As I understand “`this`”, yes. `self` is the object that received the message—in your examples, the object that something is retaining or asking the retain count of.

> If I just use assignment operator (A=B) Does it copy the pointer(self) and that's it ?

The pointer copied will only be `self` if `B` is `self`. That is, if you say `A = self`, then it will copy the `self` pointer to `A`. If you say `B = self` and then you say `A = B`, same thing, since `B` and `self` contain the same pointer. If you had not said `B = self`, then `B` is probably some other value, so that other value is what will be copied to `A`. And that's assuming `A` and `B` are pointer variables.

It will copy the value (pointer) you tell it to copy. Nothing else.

> I though it would use "copywithzone" and it's relatives and the "self" members won't be equal.

No. The object is only sent a `copyWithZone:` message (do not omit colons—they are significant) when something sends it a `copyWithZone:` message. The most common way is to send it a `copy` message, as that will send a `copyWithZone:` message in turn.

Furthermore, even a “copy” does not always copy the object. Immutable objects can implement `copyWithZone:` to return `[self retain]` instead.

However, plain assignment never copies the object. It only copies the pointer.

> Moreover, I though copywithzone is like copy constructor in c++.

Roughly. I don't know enough C++ to say how much like it it is.

Comment: Like the scenario in the commennt above yours, calling [objB retain] and calling [objA retain] will contain different "self" parameter as you said, which will make my example of "retain" function incorrect.
So who's wrong ? my understanding ? Cause i'm pretty sure the example is correct.
I just means that assignment like "SObject *objB = objA;" will cause  both objects' retain function to have the same "self" when called (or any other function)

Comment: Yes, your understanding. See the last paragraph of Eiko's answer for what happens in your `retain` implementation. When you assign `objB = objA`, there are no “both objects”; there is one object, whose pointer is in two variables. In that case, `[objA retain]` and `[objB retain]` will both send the `retain` message to the same object, which means they will both run the same implementation of `retain`, and that implementation will receive the same value of `self` both times.

Comment: Great, that's pretty much what I was thinking, as you can see from my last comment line above. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

I remember having heard that you shouldn't make any assumptions on the retainCount. :-)

self is indeed very similar to this.

Assignment just copies the pointer, and it's the same in C++.

```
NSObject *objA =[[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject *objB = objA;
```

objA and objB reference the *same* object.

Not that your code example uses [self class], so they'd use one table per class for all instances of that class.